# Using BTLE device programmatically that wasn't recognized by the system

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I used my bluetooth low energy heart rate monitor with windows 10, which works flawlessly. I could use it with my previous android phone, but my new phone does not recognize it.

How do I find and pair the hrm with oreo via own development in java if the system does not find it?

I could not find anything about this topic, therefore there is nothing that I tried.

Current phone P20 Lite.

HRM: https://www.tchibo.de/bluetooth-pulsmessgurt-p400074878.html

English: This Bluetooth® heart rate monitor wirelessly measures your heart rate (approx. 30-250 bpm) and sends the recorded signals in real time to a smartphone with a compatible training application.

Compatible with many fitness apps A free fitness app for Apple and Android devices is included. With it a targeted training and an exact evaluation are possible. The Bluetooth® heart rate monitor is compatible with many other fitness apps, for example Runtastic, Adidas MiCoach, RunKeeper, Endomondo, Runmeter.

Suitable for many devices The heart rate monitor with chest strap is suitable for iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, iPhone 5s and iPhone 6, as well as for Android devices with Bluetooth 4.0 from Android version 4.3, for example Samsung Galaxy S3/S4/S5/S6, Galaxy Note 2/3 and HTC One/One mini.

It can be used from Bluetooth 4.0 - for significantly faster connections with lower energy consumption.

Comment: You should at least [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53182046/edit) your question with the make and model of the heart rate monitor as well as your prior and current android phones.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Done

Comment: How may devices can your HRM pair with? Maybe you just have to reset it.

Comment: @Christopher "How may devices can your HRM pair with" What's that?